# How to call a function based on the changes in an array which is linked to the local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

All my components are in a primary class called `App`. I want to call the function `showData` from the `Table` Component when the array `persons` changes. An array also called `persons` in the component `Form` changes when I create a new form and submit it, automatically this array synchronizes with the local storage which leads to a change in the array `persons` in the component `Table`. so I want every time I submit something the function `showData` be called and my table updates.

App Component

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Form from './Form';
import Table from './Table'


class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <Form />
          <Table />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
export default App;
```

Table Component

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './styles.css';

let persons = [];


if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms")) !== null)
    persons = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms"));


class Table extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <table className="myTable" id="editableTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Firstname</th>
                        <th>Lastname</th>
                        <th>Date Of Birthday</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                        <th>Favorite Choclates</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Type of Work</th>
                        <th>Hobbies</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Favorite Color</th>
                    </tr>

                </thead>

                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>

        );

    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.showData();
    }

    showData() {
        let table = document.getElementById('editableTable');
        let x = table.rows.length;
        while (--x) {
            table.deleteRow(x);
        }
        let i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
            let row = table.insertRow();
            let firstNameCell = row.insertCell(0);
            let lastNameCell = row.insertCell(1);
            let birthdayCell = row.insertCell(2);
            let salaryCell = row.insertCell(3);
            let choclatesCell = row.insertCell(4);
            let genderCell = row.insertCell(5);
            let workTypeCell = row.insertCell(6);
            let hobbiesCell = row.insertCell(7);
            let descriptionCell = row.insertCell(8);
            let colorCell = row.insertCell(9);


            firstNameCell.innerHTML = persons[i].firstName;
            lastNameCell.innerHTML = persons[i].lastName;
            birthdayCell.innerHTML = persons[i].birthday;
            salaryCell.innerHTML = persons[i].salary;
            choclatesCell.innerHTML = persons[i].Choclates;
            genderCell.innerHTML = persons[i].Gender;
            workTypeCell.innerHTML = persons[i].workType;
            hobbiesCell.innerHTML = persons[i].Hobbies;
            descriptionCell.innerHTML = persons[i].Description;
            colorCell.innerHTML = persons[i].favoriteColor;
            colorCell.style.backgroundColor = persons[i].favoriteColor;


        }
    }

}


export default Table;
```

Form Component

```
import React from 'react';

let persons = [];


if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms")) !== null)
    persons = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms"));

.
.
.

handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let validation = this.validate();
        if (validation === true) {
            this.saveForm(this.state);
        }
        else {
            this.displayError(validation);
        }
    }

    validate() {
        const myForm = this.state;
        const errorsObj = [];
        if (myForm.firstName === "") {
            errorsObj.push('firstName');
        }
        if (myForm.lastName === "") {
            errorsObj.push('lastName');
        }
        if (myForm.birthday === "") {
            errorsObj.push('birthday');
        }
        if (myForm.salary === 0) {
            errorsObj.push('salary');
        }
        if (myForm.Choclates.length !== 3) {
            errorsObj.push('Choclates');
        }
        if (myForm.workType === "" || myForm.workType === null) {
            errorsObj.push('workType');
        }
        if (myForm.Hobbies.length < 2 || myForm.Hobbies.length > 4) {
            errorsObj.push('Hobbies');
        }
        if (myForm.Description === "") {
            errorsObj.push('Description');
        }
        if (errorsObj.length === 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else { return errorsObj; };
    }

    saveForm(myForm) {
        persons.push(myForm);
        localStorage.setItem("personsForms", JSON.stringify(persons)); 
    }
```

Comment: Where you submit it?

Comment: where you are updating data in localstorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_StorageEvent).

You need to add `window.addEventListener('storage', functionYouWantToCall)` to call `showData` when the storage changes.

I don't know where you want to add it because your code is kind of messy but you will need to add

```
componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('storage', this.showData)
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    window.removeEventListener('storage', this.showData)
}
```

## Edit:

As said in the comments

> ...but i want to handle changes in the array not in the localStorage. So any idea?

You can't handle changes in the array (I suppose it's the variable `persons`) because it's outside you component and also, it will never change. The value will be set once and if the value of the `localStorage` change, `persons` won't change.

That is why you need the `addEventListener`.

What you should do is store `persons` in the state of the component

```
state = { persons = [] }
```

In `componentDidMount` get the value and add `addEventListener`

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms")) !== null){
        let persons = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms"));
        this.setState({ persons })
    } 

    window.addEventListener('storage', this.handlePersonsChange)
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    window.removeEventListener('storage', this.handlePersonsChange)
}

handlePersonsChange = () => {
    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms")) !== null){
        let persons = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms"));
        if(JSON.stringify(persons) === JSON.stringify(this.persons)){
            this.setState({ persons })
            this.showData()
        }
    } 
}
```

This way, you keep the array of `localStorage` in you component's `state` and and `localStorage` you check if `personsForms` have changed and then call `showData`.

*You should notice that `JSON.stringify(persons) === JSON.stringify(this.persons)` isn't a good, but if you need better always to compare arrays, you can do a little search to that.

*Also notice that you have duplicate code that isn't needed.

You can simply this

```
if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms")) !== null){
    let persons = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms"));
```

To

```
let localStoragePersons = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("personsForms"));
persons = localStoragePersons !== null ? localStoragePersons : []
```

This way you don't access `localStorage.getItem` twice.

Comment: Thank you. this approache will definetly work, but i want to handle changes in the array not in the local storage.so any idea?